# LSTM- differences between long-term memory and short-term memory

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

How is the data classified as long-term memory and short-term memory?

Comment: Looks like off topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam Then should I change the place to ask?

Comment: May be https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam Thank you! I put this question here at first.  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27459/classifications-as-long-term-memory-and-short-term-memory-in-lstm